# When using getElementsByTagName, how to I specify which element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, getelementsbytagname

I am setting up a lightweight website for my work. It has very little JS interactivity, using only GSAP with TweenLite() for 1-2 animations. Since its nearly all unique elements, I can mostly use *getElementById()* to cover them.

One problem involving multiple similar elements is causing me grief. An accordion style menu:

```
<button>MenuOne</button>
<div>
    <a>...</a>
    <a>...</a>
    <a>...</a>
</div>

<button>MenuTwo</button>
<div>
    <a>...</a>
    <a>...</a>
    <a>...</a>
</div>

<button>MenuThree</button>
<div>
    <a>...</a>
    <a>...</a>
    <a>...</a>
</div>
```

The idea is on the click of the Menu button, the next div becomes visible, and any over divs become invisible (all hidden by default).

If I were to use jQuery, this could be achieved by

```
$('button').click(function() {

  //show/hide stuff

});
```

I don't want to use jQuery for a single selector, when GSAP covers all the animations I've used so far:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

btn.onmouseup=function () {

  //show/hide stuff

};
```

However, this doesn't seem to react to me clicking the buttons (no errors, nothing). I have the same function() inside, and can get it to work by putting the btn variable into jquery *$(btn).click(*.

I can only assume the btn variable is watching *all* buttons, and cannot distinguish which one (if any) I've just clicked. Something that jQuery library is able to do.

---

Hunting around online, I've found that the native JS result is slightly different to the jquery one. In the console, jquery shows up as an Object[array], and javascript shows as an HTMLCollectionT[array]. My guess is part of the jquery array has some marker that isn't there by default.

I found how to pick [0] [1] [2] buttons in the array and can add unique IDs, but am sure I can solve this without 3 separate functions.

Comment: Note that `getElementsByTagName` contains the term "Elements", the plural of "Element". That already tells you that this methods returns a *list* of elements. You have to iterate over that list and assign the event handler. If you look at the [**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName), you will even find an example of how to do that (iterate over the list). Always read documentation first!

Comment: Yeah, I saw that it targeted multiple elements, I just wasn't sure on how to pick out the one I was after. After using Jquery for so long I managed to avoid using for() loops, and I've never really got the hang of them.
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the list of buttons by `document.getElementsByTagName()` function, if you want to attach particular function at click of particular button then you can do like this.

```
var allButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for(var i=0; i<allButtons.length; i++){
    allButtons[i].onclick = myfunction;
}

function myfunction (){
    alert(this.id);
}
```

Here is the demo with http://jsfiddle.net/M697C/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've seen this before, but wasn't aware how it was simply wrapped around the original function

Comment: @Inspironix best of luck for this, if stuck somewhere please share it.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery binding will automatically loop through all of the captured elements, and manually bind to each one. When you are using vanilla JS, you have to do the looping yourself:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].onmouseup = function () {
        // show/hide code here.
    });
}
```